# Why Request.IsAuthenticated is taking by default Windows user identity and returning true for form authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to to hide menu items if the user is not authorized but  Request.IsAuthenticated, httpcontext.user.identity.isauthenticated is taking windows identity and turning it to true. How to make my application to only accept Forms Authentication.Thank you!!

Comment: did you set it in web.config file? something like `<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login"  />
</authentication>`

Comment: Controllers with [Authorize] is taking form authorization

Comment: but do you have authentication set to forms?

Comment: yes I added <authentication mode="Forms"> <forms loginUrl="~/Login" /> </authentication> in web config but still Request.IsAuthenticated is using windows by default

Comment: Is the loginUrl path correct in your case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118337/discussion-between-gigi-and-elenadba).